# Traceback error when running elasticsearch and kibana on python

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

```css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have an error message above. My python code(main.py) is below. I am using docker-compose to implement elasticsearch and kibana. What should I fix my code? Does my problem come from main.py or docker-compose.yml?

My main.py is below.

```css
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
 'author': 'taqkarim',
 'text': 'Testing ElasticSearch',
 'timestamp': datetime(2012, 9, 16, 0, 0), # in the far past
}

# load a tweet into ES
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['result'])

# query by id
res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1)
print(res['_source'])

es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")

# search
res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all":{}}})
print("Got %d Hits:" % res['hits']['total'])
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
 print("%(timestamp)s %(author)s: %(text)s" % hit["_source"])
```

Comment: check your es ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly set your Elasticsearch host and port, as:

```py
es = Elasticsearch([
    {'host': 'my-es-host', 'port': 9200},
])
```

Moreover check that your Elasticsearch container has its 9200 port open, for example

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
    environment:
      .... some env vars
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer get me think about my code again. And, I found out that I did `docker-compose down` and didn't `docker-compose up -d`.